# Itext pdf invalid after download

Tags: java, servlets, itext

When I download signed pdf document it is shown as invalid by Adobe Reader . I can view this file normally on server in my local project folder , but when I put this file through a process of downloading by my servlet something in this download process make a pdf invalid .
This is my servlet download code :

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=CompensationReport" + compensation+".pdf");
response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(thePdf1);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
while (true) {
    int bytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (bytesRead < 0) {
        break;
    }
    sos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    sos.flush();
}
sos.flush();
bis.close();  
return;
```

Comment: How do the files differ, i.e. the file on disc on the server and the file received by the client? Is the latter one cut off? That being asked, I'm not so sure whether accepting ranges is a good idea here.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I develop locally on my computer , when I try to open file from a project folder it is opened fine , when I download the folder using my servlet download option - Adobe Reader says : this document is invalid .Without signed signature fields the document is opened ok .

Comment: I use mozilla , it also opens dowloaded document in preview but normally as it does the browser does not show the signed fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.techper.net/2008/02/27/4-ways-to-stream-pdf-and-some-tips/) try setting Content-Length

```
response.setContentLength(filebytesize);
```

Comment: But i use ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();

Comment: This thing worked , I don't know if it was by luck  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(thePdf1);
      response.setContentLength(fis.available());

Comment: setting Content-Length is similar to setting Header and Content-Type.

Comment: @JovoKrneta `fis.available()` works for `FileInputStream` instances. For `InputStream` in general, though, `available()` does **not** necessarily return the exact total length but instead only the amount of data right now at hands.